# Cordova platform add windows EACCES error

Tags: macos, cordova, console, windows-phone

I was trying to add the windows platform (I use OSX 10.9) and the console gave me this error: EACCES.

bash-3.2# cordova platform add windows
WARNING: Applications for platform windows can not be built on this OS - darwin.

Adding windows project...

Error: spawn EACCES

```
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1155:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:988:9)
at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:100:31)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform.js:151:39
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add Windows cordova platform inside  OSX because not supported. You need to use Windows based machine.

Comment: you're right but the console said me that it was possible to download the base project! But yes, on Windows it worked! Now I'm sure that it's not possible!